# NSButton doesn't respond

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm now developing mac application for the first time. So here's my problem. At first time launch, the application shows login form inside a custom view in the main menu xib file, the login form is loaded from another `NSViewController` file. The problem is when I click the button at login form which is loaded in the main menu, it doesn't respond on click event. I've tried using `performselector` method, add `Action`, also using `IBAction`, none of them works.

Here's the code of appdelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSViewController *loginformcontroller = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    [window setContentView:loginformcontroller.view];
}
```

and at LoginViewController.m

@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize usernametxt,passwordtxt,loginbtn;

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        [loginbtn setAction:@selector(checkalogin)];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)checkalogin{
    NSLog(@"masuk");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Include this line after loginbtn setaction:-

```
 [loginbtn setTarget:self];
```

Comment: You are setting the action on your button but then you need to set the target as well.

Comment: If you don't set the target (it's *nil*), then the message is sent to the responder chain, which can be useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be dynamically setting an action for a button loaded from a nib.

It is possible that you have not actually hooked up the button to an IBOutlet in the view controller, which means that you are setting a target action for a nil object.

A better way would be to hookup of the buttons action to the correct method from within Interface Builder itself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume loginbtn  has its equivalent in Interface Builder. If so, justctrl+drag from button to view controller to create an IBACTION. No need to add action in code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the same case as mine , but if you extend that `NSButton` and you override some of the methods like `(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;` do not forget to call `[super mouseDown:event]`